# Restrict React children to be a custom type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a `Form` component that can take several children of type `FormPage`, and I don't know the components used because this `Form` can be reused in many places.

```js
export const Form = (props: FormProps) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const formState = useFormContainer(props);

  const HeaderComponent = Children.toArray(children).find(
    (child: FormPageType) => child.type.type === 'FormHeader'
  ) || <Header />;
  const StepsComponent = Children.toArray(children).find(
    (child: FormPageType) => child.type.type === 'StepsSection'
  ) || <StepsSection />;

  const filteredChildren = Children.toArray(children).filter(
    (child: FormPageType) =>
      !['FormHeader', 'StepsSection'].includes(child.type.type)
  );

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={formState}>
      <div className={classes.formContainer}>
        {HeaderComponent}
        {StepsComponent}
        <div className={classes.pages}>
          {React.Children.map(filteredChildren, (child, index) => (
            <SliderPage index={index}>{child}</SliderPage>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

A component of type FormPage needs to be defined like this:

```js
    const MyComponent: FormPage = () => {}
    MyComponent.formConfig = { //someconfig }
    // or
    MyComponent.type = 'FormHeader';
```

When I iterate over the children on my `Form` component, I should be able to access that `formConfig` property. This property will also be used in the `useFormContainer` hook to set the steps. I can have pre-steps pages, so I need to filter those components.

Why am I doing this way?

I want those `FormPage`s components to set their configuration instead of depending on a parent. This way, when creating new pages, I just need to add a new component as children without doing code in the parent.

Comment: Don't do this, pass it as a prop instead, it's unidiomatic react and is confusing. Props are idiomatic and easily understandable.

Comment: The configuration is made by component, not by an outside component. Would be something like this: <Form><MyComp1 /><MyComp2 /></Form>

Comment: "the configuration is made by component" - why does that have to be a true statement? Can you just put the config somewhere else? This sounds like a great use case for context

Comment: I don't want all the configuration in a single place. It's better to have this by component.  Each component knows what is needed for them. Better than having a parent who knows "everything" about them.

Comment: But that aside... is it possible to do what I asked in the question?

Comment: The parent doesn't know anything about them, it just knows to create a provider that can provide configuration to lower components - which is, from your edited question, the exact problem you're trying to solve. It's dependency injection and it's idiomatic react.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my self well enough in my question, but I'm certain context won't help here. Those inner pages (children) are dynamic, so this `Form` component can be reused many times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256042/discussion-between-witalobenicio-and-adam-jenkins).

Comment: Post an example child component and I can probably help you unwind this. Ultimately, you're rendering logic is upside down, you're trying to "pass props from below" instead of passing props from above. Yes, you can definitely get this to work and yes, you should definitely avoid it.

Comment: `I want those FormPages components to set their configuration instead of depending on a parent` - you're fighting your tool here. React's data flow is unidirectonal - down through the tree. A simplistic view is that your `FormPage`s should be rendering the content of your `Form` component, instead of your `Form` component rendering your `FormPage`s. That might be enough to set you on the right track.